# How to view functions called from button click to a request in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

How can I see which functions and in what order were called after I clicked on a button, before a network request is sent? Should I pause with a mouse click breakpoint or XHR/fetch breakpoint? I want to find the origin of certain variables (in this case, request headers and parameters) how were they structured or generated when passed in a request

Comment: You can stop at either of them and take a look at the call stack of the event. It allows you to go back as far back as you'd like in the execution chain.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The `Call Stack` shows the `Chain` of the `call` until the `breakpoint`

[image]

Also hovering on the `initiator` of the request in the `network` panel shows the `call stack`

Comment: Here, the breakpoint was in the script itself. What if the breakpoint is on the mouse click event? (Sources > Event Listener Breakpoints > Mouse > click)

Comment: then it would only show the `onclick` function in the `call stack`. the call stack won't show future functions

Comment: would it be possible to show them? what the the options at the top for? (skip over function call, step to next function call etc.)

Comment: i don't think there is a way to show future functions in the stack in chrome dev tools but i could be wrong. also the buttons at the top are to progress or regress the debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can use the initiator tab if you are looking for the callstack which triggered the request.
[image]